# PHP, How to make: domain.com/profile.php?user=admin

Tags: php

I'm making an profile page in PHP,

How to make an url like *domain.com/profile.php?user=admin* works in PHP? (this will show the profile of the user "admin")

Thnx!

Comment: This question *will* be closed because it is nowhere near specific enough, but I suspect you may simply be looking for [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). If not, you will need to provide a lot more information about exactly which part of this is giving you a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a database and a db connection and a selected db.

```
<?php
// Get your variable (admin)
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user"]);

// now query the db
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_user_database WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$datarow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>
```

Now use the datarow in your html.

```
<div>
    <?php echo $datarow[0] ?> <?php echo $datarow[1] ?> etc...
</div>
```

Good luck

Comment: Please do some checking on  `$_GET["user"]`. Could inject all sorts into your database!

Comment: And by that he means something like mysql_real_escape_string($user); so people cant use your var to sql inject your server. I will edit my answer